# GroupBar with MPAndroidChar (android studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, charts, mpandroidchart

I trying to make a chart with MPAndroidChar that showing on each year 3 semesters (Each semester is painted a different color) and on the top of each semester there is the avearage grades of the semester.

I Sucess to build a chart, but i dont know how to group all the semesters on 1 year.

I attached the Bar code, the xml and screenshoot after i run the app.
The code:

```
BarChart chart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);
        ArrayList<BarEntry> vals1 = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
        ArrayList<BarEntry> vals2 = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();

        ArrayList<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();

        entries.add(new BarEntry(90, 0)); //year 1 - sem 1
        entries.add(new BarEntry(69, 1)); //year 1 - sem 2
        entries.add(new BarEntry(96, 2)); //year 1 - sem 3
        BarDataSet dataset = new BarDataSet(entries, "# of Calls");

        ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
        labels.add("year 1");
        labels.add("year 1");
        labels.add("year 1");
        BarData data = new BarData(labels, dataset);
        chart.setData(data);

        chart.setDescription("# of times Alice called Bob");
```

BarChart.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/bottomSection"
        android:padding="10dp">
        <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart
            android:id="@+id/chart"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**The code result:**

[image]

**What i want (sorry about the worst editing) :**

[image]

Comment: Do you have any image that can illustrate the result you want

Comment: I added to the main post.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Multiple bar charts for that purpose 
https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/BarChartActivityMultiDataset.java

Comment: I did it , but how can i add new data to the chart?

Comment: What do you mean by new data

Comment: I mean how do i create substantially the chart - add 'year 1' and into year 1 insert the value of semA,semB,semC..

Comment: I have given you the link there is example in same

Answer (score 0):

```
    BarChart chart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);

    ArrayList<BarEntry> vals1 = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
    ArrayList<BarEntry> vals2 = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
    ArrayList<BarEntry> vals3 = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
    vals1.add(new BarEntry(90, 0));
    vals2.add(new BarEntry(69, 1));
    vals3.add(new BarEntry(96, 2));

    BarDataSet datasetSem1 = new BarDataSet(vals1, "# of Calls");
    datasetSem1.setColor(Color.RED);

    BarDataSet datasetSem2 = new BarDataSet(vals2, "# of Calls");
    datasetSem2.setColor(Color.GREEN);

    BarDataSet datasetSem3 = new BarDataSet(vals3, "# of Calls");
    datasetSem3.setColor(Color.BLUE);

    List<BarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
    dataSets.add(datasetSem1);
    dataSets.add(datasetSem2);
    dataSets.add(datasetSem3);

    ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
    labels.add("year 1");
    labels.add("year 1");
    labels.add("year 1");
    BarData data = new BarData(labels, dataSets);
    chart.setData(data);
```